# Can you rename the master node?

Tags: jenkins

- On the left is the configuration of the master node (where Jenkins is installed)
- On the right is the configuration of a slave

The slave has a field name. The master doesn't and by default its name is **master**. Is it possible to change its name from **master** to *anything else*?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well as of now Jenkins doesn't provide any such functionality to change the name of Master node. Jenkins uniquely identify it's master for default builds by name **master**, therefore in that case we cannot rename it.